# Delphi Firemonkey TListView's Item rearrange

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to rearrange TListView's Items dynamically such as, I have following items:

```
Item #1 Apple
Item #2 Banana
Item #3 Orange
and so on.....
```

I want to set Orange in Item #1, is it possible?

Comment: If you keep data and representation seperate, this is no problem. Just rearrange your data, and rebuild the ListView accordingly.

Comment: this is what I did.

Comment: Well, then what seems to be the issue, apart from the component not allowing to change an item (except for it's visual properties)?

Comment: It seems the asker wants to have the list automatically , alike TStringList.Sorted=true.

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this in 10.2 and 10.3 not sure when the TComparer came about
Here is a unit with two basic sorters - you can change the code to do whatever in the compare function

```
unit MyFMXListView_ItemSorters;

interface
uses
  System.Generics.Defaults
, FMX.ListView.Appearances
;

type
  TMyListViewItemComparer_AscendingItemText = class( TComparer<TListViewItem> )
    function Compare(const Left, Right: TListViewItem): Integer; override;
  end;

  TMyListViewItemComparer_DescendingItemText = class( TComparer<TListViewItem> )
    function Compare(const Left, Right: TListViewItem): Integer; override;
  end;

implementation
uses
  sysutils;

{ TMyListViewItemComparer_Ascending }

function TMyListViewItemComparer_AscendingItemText.Compare(const Left,
  Right: TListViewItem): Integer;
begin
  result := CompareText(Left.Text,Right.Text);
end;

{ TMyListViewItemComparer_DescendingItemText }

function TMyListViewItemComparer_DescendingItemText.Compare(const Left,
  Right: TListViewItem): Integer;
begin
  result := CompareText(Right.Text,Left.Text);
end;

end.
```

if you use this unit in your form then all you need to do is call the TListView.Items.Sort( TMyListViewItemComparer_AscendingItemText.Create  );

e.g.Basic Form

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ListView;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lv1: TListView;
    pnlTop: TPanel;
    btnAscending: TButton;
    btnDescending: TButton;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAscendingClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDescendingClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses
  MyFMXListView_ItemSorters
;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btnAscendingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lv1.Items.Sort( TMyListViewItemComparer_AscendingItemText.Create );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDescendingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lv1.Items.Sort( TMyListViewItemComparer_DescendingItemText.Create );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  myTListViewItem : TListViewItem;
begin
  lv1.ItemAppearance.ItemHeight := 24;
  lv1.Items.Add.Text := 'Banana';
  lv1.Items.Add.Text := 'Apple';
  lv1.Items.Add.Text := 'Orange';
end;
```

Three images below ( After Create, After Ascending click and after Descending click )
[image: Examples]

Comment: Yup, this will sort. But wil it sort *dynamically* so when items are added will it auto-sort the list or insert the new item at the correct spot? AFAIK TList dies not have a 'Sorted' property like stringlist does.